# How do poison counters work and how would a player get them?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

How do poison counters work? What are the scenarios a player would receive a poison counter?

Comment: This question is unclear. How did you hear about poison counters and what confuses you about them? It would be the same as asking "how do +1/+1 counters work? how does a creature get +1/+1 counters?" Many effects give poison counters (usually creatures with the *infect* keyword.) Most can be found by [searching gatherer for the word “poison.”](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?text=+[Poison])

Comment: This question is very basic, and perhaps doesn't show much research effort (you can find a lot by searching gatherer, yes) but that's not the same as it being unclear. The OP very clearly asked what the ways are that a player can get poison counters, which is a specific, answerable question.

Comment: @Jefromi It sounds to me like this is a perfect example of an X/Y problem. Like the first comment says, there's obviously some hidden information behind the question, which is important for helping the player learn Magic. So "what is your real question here?" is a fair question to ask, and the part that's unclear is what the real question is. The question as asked may be answerable, but I don't think it's actually the real question.

Comment: Perhaps - or perhaps he just read something about poison counters somewhere, maybe he saw Melira, maybe he saw a question here. ([This one](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/4780/409) was bumped last week.) So I totally agree about figuring out if there was another question behind this, but I think it's still worth answering as-is, since it probably still will let the OP figure things out even if he's asking because of something else. I'd rather err on the side of being helpful!

Comment: You currently have five open questions and zero accepted answers. Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/254466) if you don't understand how or when to accept answers.

Answer (score 2):

All you really need to know is that you lose the game if you get 10, and that [they're nearly impossible to remove](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4263/can-poison-counters-be-removed). Generally if you see a card that talks about poison counters, it'll be a card that gives them, so this should never really be confusing - if the cards don't mention them, you don't have to worry about them.

---

By far the main way to get poison counters is from creatures with Infect, like [Blighted Agent](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlighted%20Agent%5d):

> Infect (This creature deals damage to creatures in the form of -1/-1 counters and to players in the form of poison counters.)

There's was also an ability called Poisonous, but it's only on a couple cards.  [Virulent Sliver](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVirulent%20Sliver%5d) gives all Slivers Poisonous 1:

> All Sliver creatures have poisonous 1. (Whenever a Sliver deals combat damage to a player, that player gets a poison counter. A player with ten or more poison counters loses the game.)

And [Snake Cult Initiation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSnake%20Cult%20Initiation%5d) is an aura that gives the enchanted creature Poisonous 3. [Marsh Viper](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMarsh%20Viper%5d) essentially has Poisonous 2, but spells it out.

There are [several more cards](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20[poison]%20[counter]%20![infect]%20![poisonous]) that just explicitly give a player poison counters.